# SQL Server multiple table JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables

- Table 1 `[StockItem]` contains information about an item, I need only the Id from this table
- Table 2 `[Categories]` contains the categories and subcategories with their names and URL slug
- Table 3 `[ItemCategories]` contains the categories for each item and has only two columns, `CategoryId` and `StockItemId`

I have this query which now returns the category id and combined slug as category/subcategory...

```
WITH categoryPath(Id, Slug)
AS
(
     SELECT 
         Id, Slug 
     FROM 
         Categories
     WHERE 
         ParentCategoryId IS NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
         Categories.Id
         ,CAST(categoryPath.Slug + '/' + categories.Slug AS NVARCHAR(150))  
     FROM 
         Categories
     JOIN 
         categoryPath ON Categories.ParentCategoryId = categoryPath.Id
)
SELECT * 
FROM ItemCategories
JOIN categoryPath ON ItemCategories.StockId = categoryPath.Id 
WHERE ItemCategories.StockId = 5
```

The result of this query looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to add to the result the `Category Name` from the `[Categories]` table which have the column `[CategoryName]`, but I don't know how to add another JOIN to this already complex query.

Comment: please put code to create tables and some sample rows. chenqui.

Comment: The stockitem table has a lot of columns

Comment: Then, put only those columns which you are interested in. Figure out a way to create a sample case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column is indeed in that table, then you can use this `SELECT` in the CTE.

You don't need another join, you just need the name column to be part of the `categoryPath` CTE.

```
SELECT Id,
       ,Slug
       ,CategoryName 
     FROM Categories
     WHERE ParentCategoryId IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Categories.Id
     ,CAST(categoryPath.Slug + '/' + categories.Slug AS NVARCHAR(150))  
     ,CategoryName
     FROM Categories
```

Don't forget to update the CTE definition with:

```
WITH categoryPath(Id,Slug,CategoryName)
```